# Tess4J On Oracle Enterprise Linux -Native library (linux-x86-64/libtesseract.so) not found in resource path

Tags: java, linux, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I have problems during configuration and operation of the tess4j Oracle Enterprise Linux.

I installed `tesseract3.04` and `leptonica 1.71 .`
Tesseract I installed  that I download a `.tar` file unpacked and do

```
./configure 
make 
make install

# tesseract -v
tesseract 3.04.00
 leptonica-1.71
```

When I run the application in netbeans receive the following error :

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError : Unable to load library ' tesseract ': Native library ( linux - x86 / libtesseract.so )...
```

i copy  libteseract.co in  `/tmp/tess4j/linux-x86`
When i set Property `jna.library.path`  `to usr/local/lib` 
I tried to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH  than again I have the same error.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @user2696358 could you perhaps explain how you solved it?

Comment: how did you solve it